# Printing data using main from subclass in Java

Tags: java

Good morning! I have a real quick question. This is about printing the data from a subclass from an array in the main program. Please bear with me i'm rather new to this.

The program should print the Perimeter, the Area and the Average Length of a shape, which is defined in the subclass of the superclass "Shape"

But all it is printing is "Shape."

I know its just a tweak in the syntax but been trying for hours to locate where the problem is. I was wondering if any of you can give me some pointers? Thanks, your help will be much appreciated.

→ To make it easier to understand, I pasted 4 segments of my program,

1. Main (For collecting the user inputs and printing the results)
2. The Shape Superclass (Basically for defining the perimeter and area)
3. The Parallelogram Interface (Basically for the average of the sides lengths)
4. The Square Subclass (Where all the info is processed)

Main:

```
package shape;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

@author Fulltime

public class MainExecute {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Shape> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Triangle t;
        Square s;
        Trapezoid r;

        while(true){
            Scanner Choice = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a shape: ");
            String choice = Choice.nextLine();
            if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")){
                break;
            }
            else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("triangle")){
                System.out.print("Enter base of triangle: ");
                double base = Choice.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter height of triangle: ");
                double height = Choice.nextDouble();
                t = new Triangle(base, height);
                list.add(t);
            }
            else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("square")){
                System.out.print("Enter side of square: ");
                double side = Choice.nextDouble();
                s = new Square(side);
                list.add(s);
            }
            else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("trapezoid")){
                System.out.print("Enter length1 of trapezoid: ");
                double length1 = Choice.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter length2 of trapezoid: ");
                double length2 = Choice.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter height of trapezoid: ");
                double height = Choice.nextDouble();
                r = new Trapezoid(length1, length2, height);
                list.add(r);
            }
        }
        Shape q;
        System.out.println("Shapes: ");
        for(int i = 0; i <list.size(); i++){
            q = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(q.getClass().getName());
            if(q.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Triangle")){
                t=(Triangle)q;
                System.out.println("Perimeter: " + t.getPerimeter());
                System.out.println("Area: " + t.getArea());
            }
            if(q.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Square")){
                s=(Square)q;
                System.out.println("Perimeter: " + s.getPerimeter());
                System.out.println("Area: " + s.getArea());
                System.out.println("Average length of sides: " + s.getAverage());
            }
            if(q.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Trapezoid")){
                r=(Trapezoid)q;
                System.out.println("Perimeter: " + r.getPerimeter());
                System.out.println("Area: " + r.getArea());
                System.out.println("Average length of sides: " + r.getAverage());
            }
        }    
    }        
}
```

Shape Superclass

```
package shape;
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Shape {

    public abstract double getPerimeter ();
    public abstract double getArea ();

    public double Perimeter;
    public double Area;

    public void displayInfo(){
        //System.out.println("Perimeter: " + this.getPerimeter());
        //System.out.println("Area: " + this.getArea());
    }        
}
```

Parallelogram Interface

```
package shape;

@author Fulltime

public interface Parallelogram {
    public double getAverage();
}
```

Square Subclass

```
package shape;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

@author Fulltime

public class Square extends Shape implements Parallelogram {

    public Square(){}

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter (){
        Perimeter = side * 4;    
        return Perimeter;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea (){
        Area = side * side;   
        return Area;
    }

    @Override
    public double getAverage(){
        double Sides;
        Sides = (this.side + this.side + this.side + this.side) / 4;
        return Sides;
    }

    public double side;

   /**
    * @return the side
    */
    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }

   /**
    * @param side the side to set
    */
    public void setSide(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public Square (double side){
        this.side = side;        
    }

    public void printSquare(){
        System.out.println("The Perimeter of this shape is " + getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The Area of this shape is " + getArea());
        System.out.println("The Average Length of this shape's sides is " + getAverage());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Use `getClass().getSimpleName()` instead of `getClass()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [getSimpleName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29) returns the classname without the package qualification.

```
 if(q.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Triangle")){

 }else if(..) // Also use else-if
```

Or you can use `instanceof` operator

```
   if(q instanceof Triangle){
      //logic here
   }else if(..)
```

Now as a note this is not a good OO design using if-else for everywhere  you should reconsider redesign your model.

For example make `displayInformation` abstract then all concrete subclasses has to override it.

```
abstract class Shape{

 public abstract void displayInformation(); 
}
```

Triangle

```
public class Triangle extends Shape implements whatyouwant {


 @Override 
 public void displayInformation(){
   System.out.println("Perimeter: " + this.getPerimeter());
   System.out.println("Area: " + this.getArea());
 }

}
```

Square:

```
public class Square extends Shape ..{

 @Override
 public void displayInformation(){
     System.out.println("Perimeter: " + this.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("Area: " + this.getArea());
            System.out.println("Average length of sides: " + this.getAverage());
 }

}
```

So then in your main class you don't have to code any `if-else` just see polimorphism magic.

```
  for(Shape shape : list){//use enhanced loop
     shape.displayInformation();
  }
```

Comment: I don't know whether to call you brilliant, or call myself n00b. Perhaps it is both, but thank you for your input. I know most of the time the problem is just with a little tweak with the syntax. Your help is very much appreciated. :)

Comment: @SandyBites i update my answer with a object oriented solution :)